How to create generic type references in Xtext Inferrer? Like "private <T> T get(Class<T> clazz)"
I had done it several times before, and every time I had to look it up in my example. But I can't find my example in my GitHub anymore.
How can I define "generic type references" like
private <T> T getFoo(Class<T> clazz)

in Xtext Inferrer?
Thank you for your input.
I can not remember anymore.
I checked all my github repos. And did a lot of google search, but nothing helped me to go further.
Thanks a lot Florian

Xtext's Domainmodel example generates a constructor of a similar shape:
public Foo(final Procedure1<Foo> initializer)
The JVM model inferrer uses the JvmTypesBuilder as an extension:
            val procedureType = typeRef(Procedure1, typeRef(it)) /* Procedure<MyEntity> */
            members += entity.toConstructor [
                parameters += entity.toParameter("initializer", procedureType)
                // here we implement the body using black box Java code.
                body = '''
                    initializer.apply(this);
                '''
            ]

I hope this will guide you into the right direction.
